# Firefox Remote Debugging does not work

Tags: android, firefox, remote-debugging

My hosting machine is Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit and my mobile device is Vodafone 875 (Android 4.1.1).

I've done all the recommendations on the [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging) but when I try to connect I receive the following message:

**Error: connection timeout.**

I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I've followed the Firefox Remote Debugging for Android instructions exactly, as far as I can tell, but I get a timeout trying to connect to the forwarded port (tcp 6000) on my (rooted) phone and tablet. I'm issuing the ADB command listed for latest FF on the desktop and device (with no error or any other kind of output on the command line):

```
adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/firefox-debugger-socket
```

I finally had success using the old forwarding command mentioned by Mark Finkle.

```
adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000
```

This is also in a desktop FF session in safe-mode (run with flag "-safe-mode") to be sure no addons were interfering.

I'm not sure, but I wonder whether the path for the unix domain socket file requires root privileges on a rooted device, but not on stock devices. I have no idea. I'm also not sure why the old method's working. Would love to hear from an FF dev on this.

Comment: funny for me only worked the socket variant, thank you! (Nexus 4 with Android 5.0)

Answer (score 2):

I use the remote debugging feature from my Ubuntu machine to several different phones and tablets, running different versions of Android. Just make sure:

- You enable remote debugging from Firefox for Android settings UI. It's in the "Developer Tools" section.
- Connect the device using USB.
- Use ADB forwarding: adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000

I assume you have enabled the remote debugging in your desktop Firefox, since you are using the "Web Developer > Connect..." menu.

Comment: yeah, everything is done exactly as the directions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android say.  No incoming connection request ever shows up on the Android device, and on the PC the connection attempt times out.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why can't Firefox do it itself?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same Mozilla docs, to no avail (Desktop Iceweasel/Firefox 31, FF for Android up2date (39?)) - until I started the (old) command as root:

```
sudo adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000
```